# I botched the author and date of a reference – is this misconduct?

Tags: citations, homework, research-misconduct

In a homework assignment, I wrote the wrong author and date with the title of the article in reference. Would it be counted as academic misconduct?

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be counted as academic misconduct?

No, it won't be counted as academic misconduct. You might drop marks though (get some points deducted).

A mistake or error is not dishonest or misconduct. However, plagiarism, cheating (comes in various forms), deceit, falsification count as misconduct/dishonesty and would be penalised.

For pointer, see [Northern Illinois university '*definition*' of academic dishonesty](https://www.niu.edu/academic-integrity/faculty/types/index.shtml):

> *Academic dishonesty refers to committing or contributing to dishonest acts by those engaged in teaching, learning, research, and related academic activities, and it applies not just to students, but to everyone in the academic environment (Cizek, 2003; Whitley, Jr. & Keith-Spiegel, 2002).*

Comment: "A mistake or error is not dishonest or misconduct." True, but some mistakes, while not *being* misconduct, do very easily give the *appearance* of misconduct. An important point here is that the OP's mistake absolutely does not.

Answer (score 2):

##### No, not even close

Academic misconduct covers dishonest acts including deliberate plagiarism, cheating on an examination or other piece of work, or forms of research misconduct that involve dishonesty.  In the context of a homework assignment for a course, the error you made would just be considered an ordinary student mistake, and it will be marked down accordingly (if your professor even notices it).  Since your homework assignment is not published work, there is no necessity to correct the error, but you may wish to draw it to the attention of your professor in order to demonstrate that you can spot your own errors *ex post*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **"No, it is not an academic misconduct"** if it was an accident, and you try your best to correct the mistake as soon as possible.

For example, you should notify your professor or TA about this mistake via emails (or call their OFFICE phone numbers if applicable) ASAP even before they start grading the assignment.

Comment: I don’t think the professor would even notice. I would just send a new version to the Submission folder and make a note saying “updated one bibliographic entry”

Comment: +1. Errors in references are *extremely* common, and they are just that: *mistakes*, not *misconduct*. Absolutely nothing to worry about.

Comment: Maybe not phone calls ...

Comment: This is so minor a mistake it’s not worth following up on in any way.

Comment: @BenBolker, I agree that emails is better as it stays in the mailbox as a reminder for awhile. A phone call may get lost as the professor/TA would not keep track of this as super critical events.

Comment: If it were a phone call to me I would either not get it **or** be annoyed at that form of communication (I do make it clear to students that they should contact me by e-mail or by coming to office hours, not by phone)

Comment: Sorry -1 from me, whilst I agree more or less with your first point, I can’t suggest phoning a professor or even drawing attention to it.

Comment: @BenBolker, When calling a professor, everyone knows that they should call the **OFFICE** number and leave a message for class room matters. No students would call the professor's cell number ever unless specifically instructed to do so for urgent matters. BTW, a professor should not even give his/her personal cell phone number to all students in the class room.

Comment: @BenBolker, Would you please clarify 1 point ?  Do you mean to say that you would never answer any phone calls from your students when they call you at your office number  ? OR, do you only ignore this particular phone call from this particular post in this particular instance above ?

Comment: I rarely get calls on my office phone. My voice message says "if you have trouble reaching me this way you should probably send me an e-mail". I strongly prefer all of the following modes of communication with my students to phone calls: (1) in-person right before or after class; (2) in-person, office hours; (3) e-mail; (4) messages via LMS of some sort (Piazza, Canvas, etc.); (5) Zoom/Teams meeting. I have trouble imagining a student's issue that can't be handled well by one of these modes.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Undergrads calling professors (on any phone) is *extremely* out of the ordinary in the US. It should not be done, especially not over a minor error on a class assignment.